# How to remove unwanted background in an image (that has already been masked)? (Adobe illustrator CC 2019)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

First thing off my chest...

...Yes I know the image is Lego's...

... Anyways, so I was exploring how do to remove unwanted background in a clipping mask (even if the unwanted area is outlined with the pen tool) and came up empty. Here are some step to visually understand the process of the masking.

1) Added all the paths into a one compund path
2) Selected the compound path and the image
3) Make the clipping mask
How do I remove that background that was not removed during the mask? 
(The eraser tool is not working either)

[image]

Comment: Not adding as an answer because it's not what you're asking, but: next time try that on Photoshop, it's the correct tool to remove backgrounds from raster images.

Answer (score 1):

Your compound path is not correct.

If part of a compound path does not create a "hole" then the path is generally not stacked correctly before it's made into a compound shape.

Undo the compounding and ensure all the paths have the same fill/stroke and are stacked correctly. You should *see* **all 4** of the holes you have in the compound path. If you *don't* see all 4 holes in the *path*, then it's still not correct.

Then *remake* the compound path. And remake the Clipping Mask.